# Angular 2 drag & drop

Tags: angular, dom, drag-and-drop

I have these functions in my index.html of my Angular 2 project:

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", "teststring");
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    console.log(data);
}
</script>
```

When I put the functions in my component, it gives the following errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: drag is not defined at HTMLImageElement.ondragstart
Uncaught ReferenceError: allowDrop is not defined at HTMLDivElement.ondragover
```

the elements using the functions are in the component html:

```
<div> ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img> src="smiley.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
</div>

<div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no need to move your code to index.html, just do this:

Change

```
ondrop, ondragover, ondragstart, event
```

to

```
(drop), (dragover), (dragstart), $event
```

respectively in your template(html).

Comment: This should be accepted answer. This answers the actual question

Comment: I agree, I was having the same problem and this answer helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

why are you defining in the index.html file?

if you using any functions in the component html you need define these function in the component.ts file.

so move these function into component class

Comment: Because they only work in the index.html. They do not work in the component.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use drag and drop frenquently, I recommend you this library:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on how to implement HTML5 drag and drop in Angular 2:
http://www.radzen.com/blog/angular-drag-and-drop/

Comment: I've implemented this as well. Have you tried to run your app in a web worker (so your app is not blocking any longer)? See https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135. I'm asking, because it seems not to work in a web worker - unless I made too many errors ;)

Answer (score -1):

Declare a local variable to save data.

For more information  see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop